# how to append int value to GET url of retrofit in android

Tags: android, interface, retrofit, get-method

I have following url
http://54.169.227.89:90/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/2
which i wanted to use i retrofit get method
How to append 2 which is company id which i get from sharepreference during login

Here is ma interface code

```
public interface ProductsGet {


    String Company_id = OrderApplication.CompanyID_New;


    @GET("/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/")
    public void getProducts( Callback<List<ProductsNew>> response);
}
```

Comment: @selvin if u want to help then help ppl dont act over smart

Comment: @Selvin - please be constructive - that doesn't help him or the problem at hand. That is rude and who are you to say that programming is not for anyone. Everyone has every right to learn whatever they choose unless you're in North Korea :-)

Comment: thanks @blackpanther

Comment: @blackpanther *URL MANIPULATION `@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);`* ... this is on http://square.github.io/retrofit/ website ... and i think that lack of reading skill disqualifies from programming, that's it, nothing personal

Comment: @GET("/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/{Company_id}")
    public void getProducts(@Path("COMPANY_ID") String Company_id, Callback<List<ProductsNew>> response);

Comment: how to pass it getProducts() fuction

Comment: `service.getProducts("2", callback)` ... i'm not sure but check if parameters are case sensitive or not `@Path("Company_id") <=> @GET("...{Company_id}")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to make end point dynamic either you can  implementing `Endpoint` and make use of `setUrl()` or you can use URL manipulation block which is surrounded by `{` and `}`.

```
     int Company_id = OrderApplication.CompanyID_New;
        
         public interface ProductsGet {
    @GET("/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/{COMPANY_ID}") 
public void getProducts(@Path("COMPANY_ID") String Company_id, Callback<List<ProductsNew>> response);
            
            yourreference.getProducts(company_id,new Callback...)
```

Comment: `"/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/"+{companyId}` is not valid

Comment: public interface ProductsGet {

    @GET("/DataAccessService.svc/GetProducts/{COMPANY_ID}")
    public void getProducts(@Path("COMPANY_ID") String Company_id, Callback<List<ProductsNew>> response);
  
}

Comment: Yes i missed String part .Please accept answer if it worked for you

Comment: nice it help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Call<IndentsPojo> call1 = apiInterface.getReport("Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==", 1, 10,
                "",
                "", "", "",
                "01-Jan-2018", "06-Mar-2019");

   @GET("Indent/IndentVsIssueReport?")// TODO GET CALL HERE
    Call<IndentsPojo> getReports(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                     @Query("pageNumber") int pageNumber,
                                     @Query("pageSize") int pageSize,
                                     @Query("quickSearch") String quickSearch,
                                     @Query("indentNo") String indentNo,
                                     @Query("distilleryid") String distilleryid,
                                     @Query("brandcategoryid") String brandcategoryid,
                                     @Query("IssueFromDate") String fromDate,
                                     @Query("IssueToDate") String toDate
                                    );
```

[image]

Comment: Its Working using @Query parameters

Comment: Name with Green color are query parameters, in this case there is no query parameter only string attached to URL